# Qt: can't launch Windows console with QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

QProcess simply doesn't display the black console window.

This is the code I use:

```
QProcess*p=new QProcess(this);
p->start("cmd.exe");
```

Replacing cmd.exe with calc.exe successfully launches the calculator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
QProcess::startDetached("cmd.exe");
```

Comment: The following is usefull for testing commands, because it leaves the console open: `QProcess::startDetached("cmd.exe /K" + otherCommand);`